# How to say currency amount using google translate TTS?

Tags: html, unicode, text-to-speech, symbols, currency

I am using google translate text to speech, because HTML5 TTS doesn't support my language (Slovak). I have an audio tag:

```
<audio src="https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob&tl=sk&q=TEXTHERE" autoplay></audio>
```

That works very good, but I need to say bitcoin amount. I have the text "455€" it's working or "12000 CZK" it's working but I need to say bitcoin BTC or ₿ doesn't seem to work.
Thanks.

Edit: In my language, numbers are inflecting.

Comment: And what about using 'Bitcoin'?

Comment: `q=200+Bitcoin` works

Comment: @popcorn in my language its like this: 1bitcoin 2bitcoiny 5bitcoinov...

Comment: Yeah, I'm Czech too. But I don't think that this is supported by Google Translate.

Comment: `q = \`${btc} bitcoin${btc==1?"":"s"}\`` did not work.

Comment: The words exist and are correctly translated and spoken here: https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=sk&text=1%20bitcoin%202%20bitcoins%205%20bitcoins&op=translate